# How can I store the values from a WPForm in WordPress to a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How can I store the values from a WPForm in WordPress to a MySQL database?When we use WPForms where I have to add PHP part to store data? Can we store form data to tables when we are using free version of WPForms without buying it?

Comment: https://wpforms.com/    I am using this plugin.

Comment: Yes. Here is the souce code to take refrence: https://github.com/sanzeeb3/entries-for-wpforms/blob/master/includes/functions-wpfe-core.php#L59. Alternatively, https://wordpress.org/plugins/entries-for-wpforms/ the plugin itself.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using WP Forms Lite you can't do this directly, either you'll need to upgrade to PRO version or build your own custom save actions.

If you decide to go with your own custom version, some details below on how to intersect form submission on WP Forms.

WPForms has some actions you can use to do you own custom actions after form submission:

1. wpforms_process_complete

   ```
       do_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', $this->fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id );
   ```

By using on your own template or plugin the wordpress hook add_action for any of the events described, you are able to get form data and do the handling you need.

Reference for wordpress add_action can be seen on the official documentation. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Did a quick snippet that will help you get started:

```
add_action("wpforms_process_complete", 'function_save_custom_form_data');

function function_save_custom_form_data($params) {

    foreach($params as $idx=>$item) {
        $field_name = $item['name'];
        $fiel_value = $item['value'];
        // Do whatever you need
    }
    return true;

}
```

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: 1. If I have PRO version... how can it be implemented ? (without custom save action)

Comment: 2. how to get wpforms form_id in custom action ?

Answer (score 2):

WPForms store all form data in two tables within the native WordPress database. They are:

```
wp_wpforms_entries: In this table, the field values for entries are stored.
wp_wpforms_entry_meta: This table contains meta information about your entries such as IDs associated and the date that entries were submitted.
```

After publishing the form, make sure to add a form entry, so we can access the entry from your WordPress dashboard. Additionally, in your form builder, go to Settings » General and make sure that entry storing in WordPress is not disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Create custom tables for example `wpforms_entries` and `wpforms_entry_meta` in your database to store form data. Use the provided action hook `wpforms_process_complete` to store the form entries.

```
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', 'process_entry', 5, 4 );
function process_entry( $form_fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $form_id = $form_data['id'];
    $entry_data = array(
        'form_id'         => $form_id,
        'status'          => 'publish',
        'referer'         => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
        'date_created'    => current_time( 'mysql' )
    );

    // Insert into wpforms_entries custom table.
    $success = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'wpforms_entries', $entry_data );
    $entry_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    // Create meta data.
    if ( $entry_id ) {
        foreach ( $form_fields as $field ) {
            $field = apply_filters( 'wpforms_process_entry_field', $field, $form_data, $entry_id );
            if ( isset( $field['value'] ) && '' !== $field['value'] ) {
                $field_value    = is_array( $field['value'] ) ? serialize( $field['value'] ) : $field['value'];
                $entry_metadata = array(
                    'entry_id'   => $entry_id,
                    'meta_key'   => $field['name'],
                    'meta_value' => $field_value,
                );
                // Insert entry meta.
                $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'wpforms_entrymeta', $entry_metadata );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refrence: https://github.com/sanzeeb3/entries-for-wpforms/blob/master/includes/functions-wpfe-core.php#L59

Alternatively, the plugin itself is available: https://wordpress.org/plugins/entries-for-wpforms/

Answer (score 0):

Free version of WPForms does not save the entry details captured in form. Therefore, you will need to write custom code to save the values in your custom DB table and then display them.

Below hook of WPForms can be used for saving data being entered in WPForms

```
/*hook to save entries coming from WPforms into database*/
add_action( 'wpforms_process_entry_save', array( $this, 'ank_wpforms_save_entries' ), 10, 4 );

public function ank_wpforms_save_entries( $fields, $entry, $form_id, $form_data ) {
    //no need to sanitize data coming from WPForms as it is being sanitized in WPForms plugin before this hook using
    //wpforms_process_validate_{$field_type} in class-process.php
    $data                  = array();
    $data['form_id']       = $form_id;
    $data['entry_details'] = $fields;
    //additional sanity checks are also performed while json encoding in "add" before adding in database
    ank_wpforms_entry()->get_class_instance( 'entry-db' )->add( $data );
}
```

Alternatively , You can use this free plugin to save entries coming from WPForms into wordpress database and then display them in Wordpress Dashboard - https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-entries-functionality-to-wpforms/

Comment: I dont like that solution, for a few reasons.  Its not free and it doesnt let you save you data into table you have created.  I dont want to have to parse through a json string... to get my data values.